# Invalid operands to binary within an insert function

Tags: c

I am getting an "invalid operands to binary" error for the lines `pp->element == value` and `pp->left->element > value`. Sorry if the code looks terrible I'm just starting out.

```
int insert(NodeT **pp, Element value)
{

    if (pp->element == value)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    else if (pp->left->element > value)
    {
        pp->left = allocateNode(value);
    }
    
    else
    {
        pp->right = allocateNode(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: The notation problem should be dealt with by changing `pp->left` to `(*pp)->left` (assuming a `NodeT` structure contains a member `left`, and is not itself defined as a pointer type, so you actually have a triple-pointer in disguise).  Because of these possibilities (many of which have been adopted by your predecessors on SO), you really need to provide more complete code — an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).

Comment: However, after you fix the syntax issues, you will still be left with major functional issues, I think.  You aren't looking to see whether there's already a left subtree or a right subtree before you blithely overwrite `(*pp)->left`, etc.  You will need to do a lot more thinking.  You don't allocate a node until you have a null pointer in the direction you're going.  I'm not convinced you need a double pointer; I'm certain you don't need a triple pointer, but I don't know that you have a triple pointer.

Answer (score 2):

`A->B` is a syntax sugar meaning `(*A).B`.

Here `pp` is `NodeT**` and `*pp` is `NodeT*`.

Pointers don't have members, so you cannot do `pp->hoge`, which is equivalent to `(*pp).hoge`.

Replacing `pp->` with `(*pp)->` should resolve the issue.

Comment: I changed all the pp pointers to (*pp)-> but I am still receiving the same error. @MikeCAT

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your code with this patch [can compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SvVdFc1SD75vtEKc) with proper structure and function declarations.

Comment: I have my code compiling on MobaXterm and for some reason it's not compiling.